# Django Crispy Forms not loading proper templatepack

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

---I am on Ubuntu---

I am trying to setup Django Crispy forms and getting the following error:

```
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
bootstrap3/layout/buttonholder.html
```

## Settings.py template setup

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {...............
```

## Template-loader postmortem

```
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
/home/schachte/Documents/School/cse360/CSE_360_Project/CSE360_Project/ipcms/ipcms/templates/bootstrap3/layout/buttonholder.html (File does not exist)
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/admin/templates/bootstrap3/layout/buttonholder.html (File does not exist)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/auth/templates/bootstrap3/layout/buttonholder.html (File does not exist)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/crispy_forms/templates/bootstrap3/layout/buttonholder.html (File does not exist)
```

It's pretty obvious that the dir is not there that it's trying to find, but how can I make crispy forms find the correct bootstrap directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ButtonHolder` isn't part of the Bootstrap template pack. It's documented as not being so.

See [this issue for discussion](https://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms/issues/478)

Best bet is to use `FormActions` instead

Comment: Yah, so I was browsing through the files in the repo and realized ButtonHolder is deprecated. Thanks.

Comment: OMG, it helps me so much! After update crispy I had only django.template.base.TemplateDoesNotExist: my_htmnl.html in all forms which was using ButtonHolder, It was hard to understand the reason, I think it should at least throw some warning instead TemplateDoesNotExist.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you currently save your static content. The issue seems to be due to Django's inability to find your static content from bootstrap.

Comment: I just set up a new project and everything is basically at it's default. How should I resolve that so it can find it? Would crispy forms auto find the static dir defined in settings?

Comment: Yes! If you set the correct directory in your settings file, crispy forms should find it. [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/) Refer to this link when using/organizing static files. It seems you are using bootstrap3 with crispy forms. Have you downloaded bootstrap [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)?

Comment: I can remove ButtonHolder and the bootstrap text fields render with no issues. It just can't find the ButtonHolder class. I'm not sure why it's not installing it into the correct directory to begin with